# db4o viewer - Java / Linux

Tags: db4o

I need a db4o viewer for a Linux box running Java.  I noticed this post was for a .net client, but I don't have Windows and don't intend to.

Is there something I can use?  I checked out some projects, but they look like they haven't released any files yet so I haven't found anything that will work yet.

Walter

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Object Manager Enterprise](http://developer.db4o.com/Blogs/Product/tabid/167/entryid/107/Default.aspx) (or OME for short). AFAIK it is bundled with db4o java packages.

Comment: I was aware of that, but was looking for something in addition to that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use object manager that bundled with db4o distribution. Or, you can use eclipse ide plugin search Object manager. Its also called OME. 
I usually use eclipse ide to see the data, and there are query tool too.
HTH